# DVCS that integrates well with Android development?

Tags: android, eclipse, version-control, mercurial

I along with two others are collaborating to develop apps for the Android platform and want to use DVCS to manage our work.
Since all three of us are on Windows systems, we decided to go with Mercurial and its Eclipse plugin. But as I was going through some articles on around the web, I came across some hassles with the plugin such as cloned projects not being recognised as Android projects.
Though such problems can be easily fixed, are there any DVCSs that integrate well with Android development on Eclipse, maybe even tailored for a small team like ours?

Comment: Have you considered to use Git or Mercurial's console interface, instead of a GUI plug-in? Having spent some time with eGit I've noticed that I'm more productive with the console interface than in the GUI (contrary to SVN, where the GUI helps me a lot). Give it a shot and see for yourself

Answer (score 1):

I have virtually zero problems using subclipse (subversion for eclipse) and android projects. It even manages with external libraries well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have read that Distributed VCSs are better than Centralized ones, so how well do plugins of Git and other Mercurial plugins integrate with Android on Eclipse?

Comment: eGit is highly recommended. Unfortunately, i have only limited experience with android projects on git. You should edit your questions title and content if you only want experience with DVCSs.

Comment: @WinterAce - Whether it is better or not depends on your requirements and how you want to share the code.  Such blanket statements are typically more opinion than fact.  I know in my own experience I found that eclipse integration for subversion was far superior to git (granted it was a year ago), this should also be a factor in your decision.

Comment: For the record, I agree with @Robin. The GIT v. SVN vs. Hg debate is pretty silly for a small team. You should really go with familiarity and tool integration. For 3 people any VCS should be adequate.

Comment: Thank you for those comments. We will go with whatever we find easier to use.